# Why do I get weird class method redefinition errors when I compile with Visual C++ 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iterator, visual-studio-2022, redefinition

I'm trying to write my vector, to realize the function of the one in STL as much as possible.
However when I tried to run a test project, Visual Studio told me that, `const` version of `begin()`, `const` version of `end()`, `cbegin()` and `cend()` trigger `C2373` errors due to redefinitions.

I'm sure I didn't define these methods twice. Here is a minimal version to reproduce these errors.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  //for std::reverse_iterator

template <typename Type>
class vector_iterator;

template <typename Type>
class vector
{
    friend class vector_iterator<Type>;

public:
    // These alies are used as return type.
    using iterator = vector_iterator<Type>;
    using const_iterator = const vector_iterator<Type>;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    constexpr vector() noexcept{}; // simplified constructor

    constexpr vector_iterator<Type> begin() noexcept;
    constexpr const vector_iterator<Type> begin() const noexcept; // causes C2373.
    constexpr const vector_iterator<Type> cbegin() const noexcept; // causes C2373.

    constexpr vector_iterator<Type> end() noexcept;
    constexpr const vector_iterator<Type> end() const noexcept; // causes C2373.
    constexpr const vector_iterator<Type> cend() const noexcept; // causes C2373.

private:
    size_t size_ = 0;
    Type* ptr_data_ = nullptr;
};


// non-const begin(), normal
template <typename Type>
constexpr typename vector<Type>::iterator vector<Type>::begin() noexcept
{
    return vector_iterator<Type>(ptr_data_);
}

// const begin(), causes "C2373: redefinition; different type modifiers"
template <typename Type>
constexpr typename vector<Type>::const_iterator vector<Type>::begin() const noexcept
{
    return const_iterator(ptr_data_);
}

// cbegin(), causes "C2373: redefinition; different type modifiers"
template <typename Type>
constexpr typename vector<Type>::const_iterator vector<Type>::cbegin() const noexcept
{
    return const_iterator(ptr_data_);
}

// non-const end(), normal
template <typename Type>
constexpr typename vector<Type>::iterator vector<Type>::end() noexcept
{
    return iterator(ptr_data_ + size_);
}

// const end(), causes "C2373: redefinition; different type modifiers"
template <typename Type>
constexpr typename vector<Type>::const_iterator vector<Type>::end() const noexcept
{
    return const_iterator(ptr_data_ + size_);
}

// cend(), causes "C2373: redefinition; different type modifiers"
template <typename Type>
constexpr typename vector<Type>::const_iterator vector<Type>::cend() const noexcept
{
    return const_iterator(ptr_data_ + size_);
}

// simplified vector_iterator
template <typename Type>
class vector_iterator
{
public:
    explicit vector_iterator(Type* ptr) : iterator_ptr_(ptr) {}; // iterator constructor

private:
    Type* iterator_ptr_ = nullptr;
};

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> tmp; // tries to construct a vector
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio produce an error list as follows:

| Code | Description | Line (marked in the comments) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `C2373` | 'clb_container::vector<Type,Allocator>::begin': redefinition; different type modifiers | 43 |
| `C2373` | 'clb_container::vector<Type,Allocator>::cbegin': redefinition; different type modifiers | 50 |
| `C2373` | 'clb_container::vector<Type,Allocator>::end': redefinition; different type modifiers | 64 |
| `C2373` | 'clb_container::vector<Type,Allocator>::cend': redefinition; different type modifiers | 71 |

The debug log is as follows:

```bash
Build started at 21:51...
1>------ Build started: Project: Development Test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Development Test.cpp
1>Development Test.cpp(43,63): error C2373: 'vector<Type>::begin': redefinition; different type modifiers
1>Development Test.cpp(21,43):
1>see declaration of 'vector<Type>::begin'
1>Development Test.cpp(50,63): error C2373: 'vector<Type>::cbegin': redefinition; different type modifiers
1>Development Test.cpp(22,43):
1>see declaration of 'vector<Type>::cbegin'
1>Development Test.cpp(64,63): error C2373: 'vector<Type>::end': redefinition; different type modifiers
1>Development Test.cpp(25,43):
1>see declaration of 'vector<Type>::end'
1>Development Test.cpp(71,63): error C2373: 'vector<Type>::cend': redefinition; different type modifiers
1>Development Test.cpp(26,43):
1>see declaration of 'vector<Type>::cend'
1>Done building project "Development Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 21:51 and took 00.648 seconds ==========
```

I have tried the following steps:

- I commented all the methods mentioned above and recompiled it. Errors disappeared at once.
- Then I uncommented them one by one and found that whenever one of `const` version of `begin()`, `const` version of `end`, `cbegin()` and `cend()` is available, `C2373` would occurred again.
- I passed each of these code snippets to Copilot and Claude-3-Sonnet, respectively, and they found no obvious redefinitions.
- At last, I installed "C++ Clang tools for Windows under Desktop development with C++" with Visual Studio Installer, and configured the test project to use Clang. `C2373` disappeared, and the program compiled normally. However, if I changed the "Platform Toolset" back to the default "Visual Studio 2022(v143)", errors occur again. So I think this problem is probably caused by Visual C++ 2022.

However, as a part of my tiny STL, I hope it can compile normally under most compilers, rather than failing for some inexplicable reason, especially on a platform with many users like Visual Studio, but I still can't find the real problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. And copy-paste the full and complete build-log from the shown example. And add comments in the shown code where you get the errors.

Comment: This is a bit fishy `using const_iterator = const vector_iterator<Type>;`. If you look at the "real" vector class, this is not what is done there. For example, a `const_iterator` can be incremented but a `const iterator` cannot.

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` implies `const`...

```
 constexpr iterator begin() noexcept;
 constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept;
```

are the same thing, except for return type. And you can't do overloads that only differ in return type.

Still; I'm confused as to why it compiles with some compilers... so I might actually be horribly wrong...

Ok, cppreference says:

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration or non-static member function(until C++14) implies const

Are we looking at different language standards on the compilers that you tried?

Comment: I'm sorry I left out my C++ standard. My project standard is ISO C++ 20 since I wanted to use `std::strong_ordering` earlier. Therefore, I have designed these methods entirely based on the C++ 20 declaration of cppreference.
For example, [std::vector<T,Allocator>::begin, std::vector<T,Allocator>::cbegin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)  says they are `constexpr` since C++20.